# Arranging Data in a Query Table

Tags: powerquery, m

I'm trying to figure out a simple way (using PowerQuery) to convert this:

[image]

into this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I've spent days trying to figure out a simple way to do it.

Everything I've tried has failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Group By on the Transform tab, group by project and define a aggregation for each of the segment columns (e.g. Sum).
Then adjust the created code from List.Sum to List.RemoveNulls.
Then add a column with nested tables from the segment columns, using Table.FromColumns.
Remove the original segment columns and expand the nested tables.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Project", type text}, {"Segment1", type text}, {"Segment2", type text}, {"Segment3", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Project"}, {{"Segment1", each List.RemoveNulls([Segment1]), type text}, {"Segment2", each List.RemoveNulls([Segment2]), type text}, {"Segment3", each List.RemoveNulls([Segment3]), type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Tabled", each Table.FromColumns({[Segment1],[Segment2],[Segment3]},{"Segment1","Segment2","Segment3"})),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Segment1", "Segment2", "Segment3"}),
    #"Expanded Tabled" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Tabled", {"Segment1", "Segment2", "Segment3"}, {"Segment1", "Segment2", "Segment3"})
in
    #"Expanded Tabled"
```

Comment: Wow! Once again, you have really come through for me @MarcelBeug! ...with a succinct and easy to understand solution. I didn't think to use List.RemoveNulls and I had no experience with Table.AddColumn, so I definitely hadn't considered it. Thank you!

Comment: Great, Marcel! I tried but couldn't do it shorter. :)