# Merging Columns with null values PowerQuery

Tags: merge, null, powerbi, m

I have:

```
Name  Value
A     null
B     null
null  5
null  10
```

and I need:

```
Name  Value
A     5
B     10
```

Thanks a lot for providing a solution.

Comment: Can you please explain how this makes sense?

Comment: This isn't how Stack Overflow works.  You don't get to post an arbitrary question that has shown literally no research work (including how to formulate a question that is even understandable) and then expect people to solve your problem for you.  Instead, you must demonstrate (with code) exactly what the problem is, what you've tried, why it hasn't worked, and how it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284090/arranging-data-in-a-query-table), to which @MarcelBeug provided a very helpful response; which, in turn, I'm using as the basis for my answer to you for your specific table.

This requires you to use Power Query (Power BI's query editor).

For your situation, I...

1. added a column named "Group", with the word "Group" in every one of its rows
2. then I used "Group By" on that new Group column, using sum aggregation for both the Name and Value columns

[image]
[image]

3. then I edited the code that was generated in step 2...changing the occurences of List.Sum to List.RemoveNulls
4. then I added a column with an embedded table from the two lists that resulted from step 3

[image]

5. then I deleted all columns other than the Tabled column
6. then I expanded the Tabled column, which gave me this:

[image]

Here's the M code:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Group", each "Group"),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Group"}, {{"NameList", each List.RemoveNulls([Name]), type text}, {"ValueList", each List.RemoveNulls([Value]), type number}}),
#"Added Custom.1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Tabled", each Table.FromColumns({[NameList],[ValueList]},{"Name","Value"})),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom.1",{"Tabled"}),
#"Expanded Tabled" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Tabled", {"Name", "Value"}, {"Name", "Value"})
in
#"Expanded Tabled"
```

Comment: Perfect. Much appreciated! Guess thats how stackoverflow works.